# Drivers WIFI realtek HP 450 g5 doesnt work UBUNTU

Tags: drivers, realtek

ubuntu 19.04 But in this version I had worse problems, first in the installation the system came out connected but the wired network although it was connected did not provide any Internet. I only have internet when I use my cell phone with a USB cable and in USB internet mode. First I thought it was a problem of updates but after updating with the cell phone I still do not have wifi or the wired network

Comment: How far did you get in the wireless troubleshooting (or did you try).  You haven't provided us any specs about what hardware is in your machine which is found in that guide (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide esp. in the identifying device section)  What chipset did `sudo lshw -C network` report your machine has?

Comment: Hello, if I apologize I'm relatively new to this, the good thing is that I also found the solution with your help, I add it in case someone else has problems with these equipment models.

HP Probook 450 g5
** Product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
-> sudo lshw -C network   Thanks!
**
Sudo apt update
Sudo apt install -y dkms git
git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce.git
turn off network cards
enter the folder:
cd rtl8821ce
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
sudo modprobe 8821ce
Ready
verify with iwconfig
and that's it, thank you very much to this community!

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer (you can answer your own question). It allows greater formatting, is far more readable, plus you can (after a delay) accept it as the answer and gain reputation (people may also uptick it gaining you more rep).  Comments can only be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

if I apologize I'm relatively new to this, the good thing is that I also found the solution with your help, I add it in case someone else has problems with these equipment models.

HP Probook 450 g5 ** 
Product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter 
-> sudo lshw -C network Thanks! ** 
Sudo apt update 
Sudo apt install -y dkms git git clone github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce.git 
turn off network cards 
enter the folder: cd rtl8821ce sudo ./dkms-install.sh sudo modprobe 8821ce 
Ready verify with iwconfig and that's it, thank you very much to this community! –